# What is the Testament of Hezekiah? I know it exists, but I can't locate it

Tags: judaism, apocrypha, christian-literature

I am currently reading up on of apocryphal and pseudopigagraphical literature, and I see on a list that the Testament of Hezekiah is enumerated as one of them. However, I cannot locate a source or any short blurb on its date, origin, and content? Do any of you know? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a bit more research, I found reference to the "Testament of Hezekiah." It appears, that it a component of the larger pseudegraphical text, ["Ascension of Isaiah."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascension_of_Isaiah) Perhaps why I couldn't find info at first, is that it is smack in the middle of a Jewish text. "The Testament of Hezekiah" is believed to be redacted into the text by later Christians.

Theories for its dates from 1st to 3rd centuries CE. It may actually be a compilation of multiple texts that were composed at different times and later compiled together.

The overarching content of the "Ascension of Isaiah" concerns the martyrdom of Isaiah, wherein Isaiah warns King Hezekiah that Manessah (the next in line) will not continue to reign in righteousness. Once Isaiah's prophecy proves to be true, Isaiah and other prophets flee to the deserts for safety. Unfortunately, they are encountered by a false prophet, Belkira (inspired by the infaous demon, Beliar), and charges Isaiah of treason, and Manessah condemns Isaiah to death, which Belkira carries out. (Later, Isaiah ascends into the 7 heavens, etc). This is the "Ascension of Isaiah." These are the sections believed to have Jewish origins (with the parallels of the demon Beliar also being present in the Book of Jubilees, fragments found in Qumran of the Testaments of the 12 Patriarchs, and the Sibylline Books. The other proposed Jewish parallel is the method of Isaiah's death -- being sawed in half -- as accounted for in both the Jerusalem and Babylonian Talmuds).

As for "The Testament of Hezekiah" (and back to the question at hand) -- it is projected into the middle of the "Ascension of Isaiah." This is the blatantly Christian portion of the text as it concerns a vision of Christ's "future" coming, the downfall of the Christian church due to corruption, the dreadful reign of Beliar (the demon), and ultimately the Second Coming. Some scholars think there are clear codes pointing to the persecution of the Church by the Roman emperor, Nero (which early Christians thought was the antichrist).

Anyway, I'm sorry for not finding this info before I posted the question. For those interested (if any) in this Jewish-Christian hybrid text, the information was located in James H. Charlesworth's "Old Testament Pseudepigrapha" (Hendrickson Publishers, 2010).

Comment: You can always answer your own question, even if you knew the answer before asking - for example if you are looking for answers other than your own. A good answer and +1.

Answer (score 0):

There has been lots of supernatural Bible changes that has taken place, during our lifetime. I am not sure if you have ever heard of the Mandela effect. This has taken place in regards to the Testament of Hezekiah. It was once in the Bible. The Testament of Hezekiah was actually after  Chronicles. It was Hezekiah, Ezra and then Nehemiah.

I know for a fact because the book of Hezekiah was my favorite book of the Bible along with Revelations. Yes the book of Revelations had a s at the end. Another Mandela effect Bible change. The last time I recall seeing it in my Bible was around 2004. I can see the bold black lettering from the heading of the title of book that was in my Bible.

A few years ago I was floored because I went to look it up and noticed it was no where to be found in any Bible. I still get emotional upon finding that it was supernaturally removed. I know that in Revelations 22:18-19 it talks about adding to or taking away from scriptures. That lets us know that this is possible. That is why the warning is given.

I was raised in a Bible reading Christian household my parents had daily Bible studies. My mom was the one who lead the daily Bible reading. We read the Testament of Hezekiah. I grew up reading from the KJV Bible, that was what my mom read from. Unfortunately, the KJV has been the most Mandela effected Bible that has been supernaturally altered, although others have been supernaturally altered as well. There are grammatical errors as well as nonsense verses etc. Most verses begin with and. This was never part of the KJV. The LORD'S prayer has been supernaturally altered. Another gem was in Revelations 18:23 the word Pharmakeia was in the KJV Bible. When I was 17 I looked that strange word up in the dictionary because it was in the Bible. The LORD bought that to my attention during the plandemic. If you look up the word sorcery it means Pharmakeia in the Greek. That was the deception upon the whole world. I could go on and on about the 1000 of changes that have now taken place.

Getting back to the Testament of Hezekiah. I have asked others do they remember this book. Unfortunately, no one remembers it. I was praying asking the LORD about why am I the only one who remembers it. I wanted to know if anyone else may have remembered this or even a platform to discuss this. I was lead to this place. I am in my 60's now, so I am older. I can definitely say I read from the book of Hezekiah numerous times. I found a few references of it on the internet. We live in a time where history is being supernaturally altered. I believe this is where Daniel 7:25 mentions about the changes given into the devil's hand as well as him changing laws and the dividing of time and times.

There is a joke in Christian circles that preachers tell their congregation about opening up the book of Hezekiah. I  do not find it funny, because it is seared in my mind. I would stake my life upon it. I read from that book often. There is also scripture stating how the word will be taken away. People will search for it and not be able to find it. I believe that is in Amos 8:11-12. I definitely believe we are the end times generation the Bible speaks about.  I know this question has been asked a few years ago. I pray that this reaches you. This is my experience concerning the Testament of Hezekiah. GOD bless and may we endure to the end.

Comment: Things are being removed from the Bible and people's memories are being wiped?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).